# Python - adding multiple tables into a single CSV with Panda

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I'm wondering how to get parsed tables from panda into a single CSV, I have managed to get each table into a separate CSV for each one, but would like them all on one CSV. This is my current code to get multiple CSVs:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

url = "https://fasttrack.grv.org.au/RaceField/ViewRaces/228697009? 
raceId=318809897"

data = pd.read_html(url, attrs = {'class': 'ReportRaceDogFormDetails'} )

for i, datas in enumerate(data):

    datas.to_csv("new{}.csv".format(i), header = False, index = False)
```

Comment: Is the schema for all tables same?

Comment: yes the schema is the same

Answer (score 4):

I think need [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) only, because `data` is list of DataFrames:

```
df = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv(file, header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: You can use `axis=1` in `concat` to put the dataframes side-by-side instead of one after the other (not sure which one you want).

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 options:

1. You can tell pandas to append data while writing to the CSV file.

   ```
   data = pd.read_html(url, attrs = {'class': 'ReportRaceDogFormDetails'} )
   for datas in data:
       datas.to_csv("new.csv", header=False, index=False, mode='a')
   ```
2. Merge all the tables into one DataFrame and then write that into the CSV file.

   ```
   data = pd.read_html(url, attrs = {'class': 'ReportRaceDogFormDetails'} )
   df = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)
   df.to_csv("new.csv", header=False, index=False)
   ```

---

### Edit

To still separate the dataframes on the csv file, we shall have to stick with option #1 but with a few additions

```
data = pd.read_html(url, attrs = {'class': 'ReportRaceDogFormDetails'} )
with open('new.csv', 'a') as csv_stream:
    for datas in data:
        datas.to_csv(csv_stream, header=False, index=False)
        csv_stream.write('\n')
```

Comment: Thankyou! Would you know how to somehow still seperate the tables during the concat? So they aren't straight after one another? Like have one row of space between

Answer (score 0):

```
all_dfs = []

for i, datas in enumerate(data):
    all_dfs.append(datas.to_csv("new{}.csv".format(i), header = False, index = False))

result = pd.concat(all_dfs)
```

Comment: This can be a one-liner with list comprehension, but I chose the form above for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm getting an error with that code

ValueError: All objects passed were None